# cmake regex to parse http_proxy environment variable

Tags: regex, cmake

I'm trying to parse the http_proxy environment variable and I've run into some problems. In bash it's pretty straightforward to do that as follows:

```
http_proxy_re='^https?://(([^:]{1,128}):([^@]{1,256})@)?([^:/]{1,255})(:([0-9]{1,5}))?/?'
```

The problem is that I need to do the same in CMake. I'm aware that the regex support in CMake is very limited. So far I've only been able to come up with something like this:

```
string (REGEX REPLACE "^https?://([^:]+):([^@]+)@([^:/]+):([0-9]+).*$" "\\1 and \\2 and \\3 and \\4" RESULT "https://user:pass@localhost:8080")
```

It works, but only if user and password are provided. ? after @ doesn't seem to solve the issue. Is there a way to make user and pass optional in this context?

Comment: what's your purpose?

Comment: @EmilyE. to pass parsed data to java machine that will run in a different platform with a different system that has no environment vars, if you care

Answer (score 1):

`?` does work in CMake's RE but you cannot make reference to `\N` when if it matches nothing. You can use `if` to check which pattern it really matches.

```
[STEP 101] # cmake --version
cmake version 3.7.2
[STEP 102] # cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

set(proxies "https://user:pass@localhost:8080" "https://localhost:8080")
set(re1 "^https?://([^:].*):([^@].*)@([^:/].*):([0-9]+).*$")
set(re2 "^https?://([^:/].*):([0-9]+).*$")
set(replace_re "^https?://(([^:].*):([^@].*)@)?([^:/].*):([0-9]+).*$")
foreach(proxy ${proxies})
    if(proxy MATCHES "${re1}")
        string(REGEX REPLACE "${replace_re}" "\\2 \\3 \\4 \\5" RESULT "${proxy}")
    elseif(proxy MATCHES "${re2}")
        #
        # Here you cannot reference to \2 and \3 or CMake would complain
        #
        string(REGEX REPLACE "${replace_re}" "<n/a> <n/a> \\4 \\5" RESULT "${proxy}")
    endif()
    message("${RESULT}")
endforeach()
[STEP 103] # cmake .
user pass localhost 8080
<n/a> <n/a> localhost 8080
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /root/tmp
[STEP 104] #
```

Comment: Your solution handles the REs the OP has come up with properly but I would replace his RE `[^:].*` (a sequence of a character that is not a colon followed by zero or more arbitrary characters) with `[^:]+` (a sequence of one or more characters that are no colons). Same applies to `[^:/].*` and `[^@].*` It's slightly different and may not apply to this case but you never know where your input comes from.

Comment: @vre you are right, that was originally my mistake and I probably need to fix this

Comment: @pynexj your solution works, but repeating pattern matchings are something that I wanted to avoid in the beginning...